# phpbb Login Transfer?

Tags: php, html, forms, phpbb

I have been working away on my website and have run into a bit of a problem. I followed this tutorial:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jq4csat4jNU&list=FLqRayDXYkEpNeTDbfJ5oBmw&index=2 to integrate the login from phpbb(and the user database) to my websites homepage. The only problem is, when you go to the forums after loggin in on the homepage login form, it asks you to log in again. Is there any way to have it log in to the forums from the original homage login form? Thanks a bunch, Josh

Here is my homepage login form code:

```
<div class="login_box">

<li>

<?php
//ob
ob_start();

//session
session_start();

    //connect
    $error = 'Could not connect to the databse';
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die($error);
    mysql_select_db('phpbb') or die ($error);

    //include functions.php phpbb script
    require 'includes/functions.php';

    if ($_POST['login'])
    {
    //get form data
    $username = addslashes (strip_tags(strtolower($_POST['username'])));
    $password = addslashes (strip_tags($_POST['password']));

    if (!$username||!$password)
        echo "Please enter a valid username and password<p /p>";
    else
    {
    //find username
    $find = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users WHERE username_clean='$username'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($find)==0)
        echo "Username not found";
    else
    {
     while ($find_row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($find))  
     {
      //grab password hash for user
      $password_hash = $find_row['user_password'];
      }
    $check = phpbb_check_hash($password, $password_hash);
    if ($check==FALSE)
        echo "Incorrect Password";
    else if ($check==TRUE)
    {
     $_SESSION['username']=$username;
     header("Location: index.php");
     exit();
     }  
    }
    }
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
?>  

<div class="logged_out">

<form action="login.php" method="post"> 

<input type="text" placeholder="username" maxlength="20" size="16px" name="username"  /> 


<input type="password" placeholder="password" maxlength="50" size="15px" name="password"  /> 

<div class="button"><input type="image" name="login" value="Log in" src="images/login.png"  width="26px" onmouseout="this.src='images/login.png'" onmouseover="this.src='images/loginhover.png'" onmouseout="t"></div>

</form> 
<a href="register.php">New member? Register now</a>

</div>

<?php
}
else
{
  echo "<div class='logged_in'>";
       echo 
            "<div class='welcome'><b>".$_SESSION['username'].".</b></div>" 
           ."<div class='account'><a href=\"userinfo.php?user=$session->username\">Messages</a></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;"
           ."<div class='account'><a href=\"useredit.php\">My Account</a></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
       echo "<div class='account'><a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></div>";
       echo "</div>";
}
?>

</li>



</div>
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside every file in use?

Comment: May or may not make a difference, but try to put spaces between `!$username` and `!password` here `!$username||!$password` such as `!$username || !$password`

Comment: Does not affect your problem but you have an unclosed `<p>` tag in `echo "Please enter a valid username and password<p /p>";`. Should read as `echo "Please enter a valid username and password<p></p>";`. Actually you can even delete `<p /p>` altogether.

Comment: yes, I added session_start to every file, bit it didn't do anything. added the space, didn't do anything, and i fixed the /p> thx for that btw. The tutorial only made it so you wouldn't have to register a new account to log in. I don't think it intend to "auto" login like I am describing here. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just an added suggestion. Try if `(isset($_SESSION['username']))` instead of `$_SESSION['username']=$username;`, see what that does.

Comment: that didn't do anything either... hmmm

Comment: What if you were to use `require_once 'includes/functions.php';` instead of `require 'includes/functions.php';`.

Comment: And this line `<a href=\"userinfo.php?user=$session->username\">` seems questionable. I don't see anything assigned to the `$session` variable. Maybe it should be `<a href=\"userinfo.php?user=$_session->username\">` with an added underscore in `$_session` (or use uppercase $_SESSION->username or add $ sign to username $_SESSION->$username) if it's not a variable that's assigned otherwise.

Comment: oh yeah, that line was from a different code, I just haven't changed it yet. That is just an extra button to be added later on.

Comment: Ok, so my suggestion about `require_once` didn't work neither?

Comment: Then I don't know what else it could be, sorry.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway though